# GTA 5 email problem

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I forgot what email I used for my Grand Theft Auto 5 account on PC, and now I wonder how I can check it out. I have tried looking it up inside the game, but it does not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you can try:

- See if you're still logged in on Rockstar's website in any of the browsers you use.
- See if you have a password vault in one of your browsers that saved that account information for you.
- [Contact Rockstar support](https://support.rockstargames.com/categories/200013306). Create a new account if necessary.
- Log into any of your email accounts you think you might have registered with and search for emails containing 'Rockstar' or 'Social Club'.
- Depending on the service you use or bought the game from, there might be options there to recover the email address you used.
- Try logging in to other Rockstar games you have, to see if that Social Club account is the same as the one you use in GTA V.
- Try 'brute-forcing' your way in with all the email addresses you have. This might take a while, but also teach you to remember or write down your account information :)